# Saving data on object for each user in a nosql database (Mongo)

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, database-design, nosql

I have a REST API which serves from a database in MongoDB. Say each JSON unit that is served contains data about a film. I'd like my users to tick whether they've seen a film or not. My problem is that, being a beginner, I am not sure how this should be implemented.

I somehow need to save this *for each user*. Right now my mongo database just holds all of the films *in general*.

Could you give me an example of how this would be accomplished in a no-sql database? What if I want to save more detailed data like when a user takes private notes related to a certain film?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have a table that has the user_id, the movie_id and the boolean, which mean if there is movie_id and a user_id the boolean is true if not it remains false that's how I would implement it.

Comment: ah okay, i understand! thanks a lot! If I have more data to save, would I split this up into several tables or would it be ok to simply put it all in one table that has `user_id` & `movie_id` and then fields like `checked?:true/false` `notes:[note1,note2, ...]` ?

Comment: i would create a table with the name `watched_film` with the parameters of the `movie_id` `user_id` and a boolean `watched`

Answer (score 0):

You can have movies data some what like this which contains unique ID for each movie

```
movie={
   id : <MOVIE_ID> //some movie ID
   name : <MOVIE_NAME> //some name
   ... //other info you want to store
}
```

then you can save each movie that user had watched in his user data in a array

```
user = {
  id : <USER_ID> //some user id
  name : <USER_NAME> //some name
  watched_movies : [<MOVIE_ID1>,<MOVIE_ID2>,.....] //movie IDS
  ... //other data about user
}
```

while you rendering all movies for particular user you just need to traverse these array and mark check for movie if user have already watched that movie